# htaccess RedirectMatch messing up subdirectories with same match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

using

```
RedirectMatch 301 /m/(..*) http://example.com/$1
```

to redirect from http://sub.site.com/m/link to http://example.com/link

thought it was working great until it tries to load thumbnails from http://example.com/data/avatars/m/0/2.jpg?1599539541

it changes it to http://example.com/m/0/2.jpg?1599539541 which will not do

spent hours googling and playing with htaccess redirects and RewriteRule
doesn't work at all
neither does

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /m/. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L]
```

been pulling my hair out for a couple days and probably irritating a few other people close by...

Comment: How about `RedirectMatch 301 ^/m/(..*) http://example.com/$1` ?

Comment: Thank you! that ^ did the trick. I had tried it previously but with several people saying it I tried it again and FAIL... then thought about clearing the cache... VICTORY

Answer (score 0):

Your [`RedirectMatch` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) regex is no good. You should change regex to `^/m/(.+)`, means matching `/m/{any_characters}` only at the starting position.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/m/(.+) http://example.com/$1
```

Comment: That part is working exactly the way it should. Trust me was a headache figuring out I needed the extra dot. That extra . is intentional. the * means what is right before it is optional. I do not want /m/ to redirect, only /m/. and /m/..* or in otherwords I ONLY want it to match /m/{any_characters} but NOT /m/{nothing_here}

Comment: `(.+)` is the right way, means one or more characters

Comment: Oh, thanks for the second reply, I didn't read it correct the first time. I will try that now.

Comment: THANKS a ton!! Turns out my biggest problem was I needed to clear my browser cache between editing 301 redirects... But you saved me for sure! Needed that ^ but also changed the ..* to .+